# Is there any reasonably easy way to provide and stream .avi and .wmv videos on web browser?

Tags: video, browser, streaming, html, avi

Is there any reasonably easy way to provide .avi and .wmv videos on webpages and later stream the videos directly off the web browser?

I realize there might have been similar questions asked around google in the past, I wanted to see if there are any update on this topic from experts out there.

Thanks,

Hank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AVI format will cause you problems if you want the easiest method - which is to simply use the video element of HTML5.

You could encode the AVIs to a web format - there are [loads](http://www.koyotelab.net/video-software/free-video-converter.html) of free services that will do it.

```
<video>
  <source src="movie.mp4" />
  <source src="movie.webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks man... I'm actually using mplyaer mencoder to convert .avi to .mp4 at the moment. Unfortunately, I am seeking an alternate option that does not require so much computation time. What sort of problems would html5 cause with .avi streaming? Will the user be forced to download the .avi before streaming it with an secondary software?